# update / save a same xml in .Net c#

Tags: c#

I m trying to edit a xml file. After update my value, i would like to save it in same original xml file. When i attend to save into this file, i have an error "could not save into this file because it still open". Need some idea | help.

Thanx :)

```
public void writeConfig(string withConfig, string param)
    {

        XmlTextReader reader = new XmlTextReader(pathFile);

        XElement xmlFile = XElement.Load(reader);
        reader.Close();

        var query = from c in xmlFile.Elements("config").Attributes(withConfig) select c;

        foreach (XAttribute config in query)
        {
            config.Value = param;
        }

        xmlFile.Save(pathFile);
    }
```

Comment: Do you... have it open somewhere else?

Comment: not at all, only open in this method

Comment: reader.Close(); this doesn't feel right, don't really know the api but closing something then save on it its kind weird

Answer (score 0):

It worked fine for me, even when I had the file open in TextPad.

Did you try looking into the current processes to see if any other program is holding that up? You can try using [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to look for such processes.

Comment: i ever have a look with Process Explorer and there is nothing using my xml file... always have an exception "file is open by an other process".

Comment: ok, found problem ! I m a idiot ! Didn't close the file when I read content with an another method. Thanx for help :)